# ho can I get the number of the current post instead of the post id?

Tags: posts, count

let say i have these post:

- firstpost
- secondpost
- thirdpost
- fourthpost

if th currentt post is secondpost, I need to return the nr: 2, if the current post is fourthpost, I need to get the nr: 4, but not the post ID!

Comment: If you are in a loop, you can use `$query->current_post()` to get the current post number in the loop.

Answer (score -1):

It could be you need offset param in query

```
$args =  array( 
    'posts_per_page' => 1 // Display only 1 post 
    'offset' => 3 // Display 4th post
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```